# Using an if statement to match x/y coordinates in Python using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

In the below code I have new_turtle (6 of them) moving horizontally from left to right on screen and bad_turtle moving vertically from bottom to top and back again. What I am looking for is when bad_turtle "runs into" or has the same x,y coordinates as new_turtle I want whichever new_turtle it "hits" to turn brown. I have tried to write this in my last if statement below but it is not working. How can this be done? Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

is_race_on = False
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=500)
user_bet = screen.textinput(title="Make your bet!", prompt="Which turtle will win the race? Enter a color: ")
print(user_bet)
colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange"]
y_positions = [175, 100, 25, -50, -125, -200]
all_turtles = []

bad_turtle = Turtle(shape="turtle")
bad_turtle.up()
bad_turtle.goto(140, -200)
bad_turtle.right(270)

for turtle_index in range(0, 6):
    new_turtle = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    new_turtle.color(colors[turtle_index])
    new_turtle.up()
    new_turtle.goto(-230, y_positions[turtle_index])
    all_turtles.append(new_turtle)

if user_bet:
    is_race_on = True

while is_race_on:

    for turtle in all_turtles:
        if turtle.xcor() > 230:
            is_race_on = False
            winning_color = turtle.pencolor()
            if winning_color == user_bet:
                print(f"You've won! The {winning_color} turtle is the winner!")
            else:
                print(f"You lost! The {winning_color} turtle is the winner!")
        rand_distance = random.randint(0, 10)
        turtle.forward(rand_distance)
        # rand_bad = random.choice(y_positions_bad)
    rand_distance_bad = random.randint(20, 40)
    bad_turtle.forward(rand_distance_bad)
    if bad_turtle.ycor() > 200 or bad_turtle.ycor() < -200:
        bad_turtle.right(180)
        bad_turtle.forward(rand_distance_bad)

    if bad_turtle.xcor() and bad_turtle.ycor() == new_turtle.xcor() and new_turtle.ycor():
        new_turtle.color("brown")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ErickY.Carreno's answer is a step in the right direction, but misses a key point.  Turtles wander a floating point plane -- when they return to the same place, it isn't necessarily exactly the same place (e.g. 13.99999 vs. 14.00001).  Using `==` is not viable.  So instead, we test for collision using a distance comparison:

```
if bad_turtle.distance(new_turtle) < 20:
    new_turtle.color("brown")
```

Where `20` can be whatever minimal distance works best for you.

The next problem, is you have your collision in the wrong place in your code and it references `new_turtle` which is no longer an active variable at this point in the race.  Fixing all the above and tweaking other aspects of your program:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

RUNNERS = [('red', 175), ('blue', 100), ('green', 25), ('yellow', -50), ('purple', -125), ('orange', -200)]

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=500)

is_race_on = False

user_bet = screen.textinput(title="Make your bet!", prompt="Which turtle will win the race? Enter a color: ")

print(user_bet)

if user_bet:
    is_race_on = True

bad_turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle')
bad_turtle.speed('fastest')
bad_turtle.up()
bad_turtle.goto(140, -200)
bad_turtle.right(270)

all_turtles = []

for color, y_position in RUNNERS:
    new_turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle')

    new_turtle.color(color)
    new_turtle.up()
    new_turtle.goto(-230, y_position)

    all_turtles.append(new_turtle)

while is_race_on:
    for turtle in all_turtles:
        if turtle.xcor() > 230:
            is_race_on = False

            winning_color = turtle.pencolor()
            if winning_color == user_bet:
                print(f"You've won!", end=' ')
            else:
                print(f"You lost!", end=' ')
            print(f"The {winning_color} turtle is the winner!")
        elif bad_turtle.distance(turtle) < 20:
            turtle.color('brown')
            all_turtles.remove(turtle)
        else:
            turtle.forward(randint(0, 10))

    if abs(bad_turtle.ycor()) > 200:
        bad_turtle.right(180)
        bad_turtle.forward(abs(bad_turtle.ycor()) - 200)

    bad_turtle.forward(randint(20, 40))

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much @cdlane! However, when I use the above it changes just the first turtle it collides with to brown but when it collides with others afterwards the colors of the remaining turtles stay the same. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Mamdlv, see the rework of your code that I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you if statement is incorrect you could try changing this:

```
if bad_turtle.xcor() and bad_turtle.ycor() == new_turtle.xcor() and new_turtle.ycor():
        new_turtle.color("brown")
```

To this:

```
if bad_turtle.xcor() == new_turtle.xcor() and bad_turtle.ycor() == new_turtle.ycor():
        new_turtle.color("brown")
```

Comment: thanks, but I am still getting the same results.